How to estimate the approximate heading between two coordinates?
I'm having some issues regarding a navigation exam question.

Place A 57N 176(deg)W and place B 60N 177(deg)E. Calculate the difference in longitude and approximate heading from B to A.

The answer key says the difference in longitude is 7 deg (which I was able to calculate) and approximate heading 130 deg which I don't know how to calculate

@Bianfable I see, the website seems handy and I'm assuming you calculate the bearing using the formula given in the website? as the book I'm using hasn't mentioned anything about calculating headings in the chapter

Are you allowed to use a chart?

Usually in these kind of questions there is really nothing to calculate, they only test if you have understood the concept. So after figuring that you will cross from Eastern to Western hemisphere figure out towards which quadrant you are moving to and what is “more” and what is “less” and then choose the appropriate answer.

This is the type of thing that can be estimated using a flight computer, and I don't mean a digital computer, but a glorified slide rule.

@busdriver, good point.  If it's multiple choice you may be able to eliminate 3 out of 4 if you know you need to go southeast-ish.

If you want a simple way to approximate the answer - consider where it happens
At ~60 degrees, each "latitude degree" is still the same distance unit as everywhere
While "longitude degree" would only be of length $cos(\approx 60^\circ) \approx \frac{1}{2}$
In the task you need to move 3 degrees south and 7 degrees east - roughly twice more of roughly twice shorter units
So, roughly, you need to travel $45^\circ$ south-east, which is heading $135$
Considering that our whole travel is to the south of latitude 60, and since we are traveling slightly more than twice to the east (7:3 not 6:3) - you can adjust slightly more to the east, but specific adjustment is a bit to your whim.
$130$ I guess is just a round number in the neighborhood, making it more of an obvious choice than the others

Usually, questions asking you for a heading from A to B present you with a chart excerpt, or the exam requires you to have a specific sectional to hand - in my experience at least.
Having said that, A little bit of maths (or programming, if you're so inclined) can solve this problem. The main details of the calculation (in both Javascript and as Excel formulas) is detailed on https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

This formula is for the initial bearing (sometimes referred to as forward azimuth) which if followed in a straight line along a great-circle arc will take you from the start point to the end point:1
Formula:   θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )
where:  φ1,λ1 is the start point, φ2,λ2 the end point (Δλ is the difference in longitude)

And then the final bearing

For final bearing, simply take the initial bearing from the end point to the start point and reverse it (using θ = (θ+180) % 360).

* Note: Your inputs in degrees need to be converted to angles in radians for the formula!
If you took the average of initial and final bearing it gives you an answer of 129.32 which is pretty close to your book answer of 130 degrees.
Javascript code used to test this out:
const lat1 = 60
const lon1 = 177
const lat2 = 57
const lon2 = -176

//φ is latitude, λ is longitude
const λ1 = lon1 * Math.PI/180
const λ2 = lon2 * Math.PI/180
const φ1 = lat1 * Math.PI/180
const φ2 = lat2 * Math.PI/180

const y = Math.sin(λ2-λ1) * Math.cos(φ2);
const x = Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2) -
          Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(φ2)*Math.cos(λ2-λ1);
const θ = Math.atan2(y, x);
const initialbrng = (θ*180/Math.PI + 360) % 360; // in degrees

const y2 = Math.sin(λ1-λ2) * Math.cos(φ1);
const x2 = Math.cos(φ2)*Math.sin(φ1) -
          Math.sin(φ2)*Math.cos(φ1)*Math.cos(λ1-λ2);
const θ2 = Math.atan2(y2, x2);
const finalbrng = ((θ2*180/Math.PI + 360) + 180) % 360; // in degrees

console.log("initial vs final", initialbrng, finalbrng)
console.log("average heading", (initialbrng + finalbrng)/2)

You can see this in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/0tgchsp6/

Just wondering, are pilots expected to remember such precise math for the exam? I mean, if they only asked for an approximate bearing, then aren't you allowed to calculate it approximately, with simplish math?

@IgorG, not in the US for any exam I have taken.  For this reason I favor the other answer - simple is best.

You are going FROM 57N TO 60N so you are going 3 degrees North.
You are going FROM 176W to 177E. Note the change from W to E which means you are crossing the dateline and have to remember to add or subtract 180 degrees. (There is no 180W or 180E meridian because they start at zero not 1)
To get from 176W to 177E, one degree at a time, you go West, stepping one degree at a time through 177W, 178W, 179W, 179E, 178E, to 177E, a difference of 6 degrees longitude on a heading that is two parts West for each part North or WNW (or 292.5 degrees).

This is wrong! The difference in longitude is 7 degrees because there is 180W and 180E, they are just the same.

Just do the subtraction with appropriate signs: 176°W = -176°, 177°E = +177°. Going from 176°W to 177°E is moving 177 - (-176) = +353°, meaning 353°E or 7°W, depending on which direction you fly around Earth.
